# Jasny Off canvas push menu - how to display open on certain pages of my website?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

I have used the [offcanvas push menu](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-push/) on my website. I want the menu to be opened on certain pages of my site on page load, but the toggle still wok for the viewer to close it / open again if they wish.

How would i set the menu to be open only on certain pages? (pages which all use the same template so I can add custom js to this template only).

I have been looking at the [methods and venets in the documentation](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas),but can't work out how to do what i need.

I have tried the 'show' method in just the page template I want the menu to load open on:

```
<script>
  $(function () { $('.navmenu').offcanvas('show'); });
</script>
```

it works by loading page with the menu open; but laid OVER the 'canvas' (body) - rather than pushing the body off canvas as it does usually. Other than adding this extra jquery to my page i have used the same code as in [Jasny's example](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-push).

### [See the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lucyryder/s3r4pnjh/13)

Many thanks!

Comment: What did you try? Could you show your actual code that manage this part?

Comment: Since i first wrote - I have tried the 'show' method in just the page template I want the menu to load open on: 
<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.navmenu').offcanvas('show');
    });
</script>

- it works by loading page with the menu open; but laid OVER the 'canvas' (body) - rather than pushing the body off canvas as it does usually.

Other than adding this extra jquery to my page i have used the same code as in Jasny's example:
http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-push/

Any help massively appreciated thanks!

Comment: I'm going to do a JS fiddle shortly....

Comment: You might get more answer when this is done as we are pretty much in the dark now

Comment: Sorry for the delay - here is the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/lucyryder/s3r4pnjh/13/

- it is part of Bootstrap Jasny extension so had to include all Bootstrap styles and js.
- at the bottom of the js panel this is what shows the menu open on page load:
 $(function(){
        $('.navmenu').offcanvas('show');
            });

- with this 'show' method the menu sits OVER the rest of the page, whereas without it the menu PUSHES the rest of the page 'off canvas' - which is how I want it - pushing the page off screen; not sitting over it.

Comment: For future reference, you should use "External Resources" on jsfiddle to load external CSS and JS (eg from [cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/)), instead of in-lining all CSS and JS.

Comment: Thansk for this will do next time

Answer (score 1):

The `data-*` attributes of the button are only used when clicking the button. *This is kind of a misdesign of the off canvas plugin.*

In this case you shouldn't use the data attributes at all, initialize it in JavaScript instead.

```
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('.navmenu').offcanvas({
      toggle: "offcanvas",
      target: ".navmenu",
      canvas: "body"
    }).offcanvas('show');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi - this works great in opening the menu on page load, but then if i close, it, i can't open it again? - is there a way we can have it so it can be re-opened again?